# textbox not getting refreshed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, textbox

i am doing an ajax call and i refresh a partial view.  Inside the partial view i have this:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("instance.Id", Model.Id)%>
```

when i put a breakpoint here over **Model.Id** it has a number in it but after the ajax refresh is done the textbox just shows up with a 0. When i do a full browser refresh, the correct number shows up in the textbox.

when i use firebug to look at data in my callback i see this:

```
<input id="instance_Id" name="instance.Id" type="text" value="0" />
```

Everything else in the partial view refreshes fine.

any ideas on what could be going wrong here?

Comment: How are u refreshing the partial view?

Comment: Post your ajax code and the controller receiving the call please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed the code above to hand roll the creation of the textbox (instead of using Html.Textbox and everything worked fine.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged the AJAX call (Firebug/Fiddler) to make sure the data is coming across?  I suspect there is code running in the "host" Action that is not running in the AJAX Action...

Comment: @Dave Swersky - i updated the question with what came back from the ajax call when i used firebug . .